# How to absolutely prevent overfull lines in ConTeXt?

Tags: line-breaking, context, section-titles, overfull

I have worked with ConTeXt for a few years now and I am well aware that the algorithm for determining line breaks is not looking at each single line in isolation, but basically trying to minimise "badness" over the whole paragraph. So, sometimes, having overfull lines is just "part of the game" and has to be minimized by using `hz` or `fullhz`, `hanging`, `tolerant` or `verytolerant`, `stretch` and so on.

However, I am now facing the situation that I would *really* like to *absolutely, totally, ultimately and always* prevent overfull lines in a section head. I.e. no matter how "bad" the line becomes according to TeX's algorithm, it should *never* resort to overfull lines. I have created an MWE that illustrates my problem:

```
\definefontsize[e]
\definefontsize[f]

\definebodyfontenvironment[default][
  a=1.200,
  b=1.400,
  c=1.728,
  d=2.0,
  e=4.0,
  f=24.0,
  x=0.9,
  xx=0.8,
  big=1.2,
  small=0.8]

\setuphead[section][
  style=\tfe\em,
  align={flushleft, nothyphenated, fullhz, hanging, verytolerant, stretch},
  number=no,
  alternative=margin,
  after={\blank[4*line]},
  ]


\starttext

\section{Test overfull headings}

\input{knuth}

\input{knuth}

\stoptext
```

which looks like this:

[image]

How can I tell the algorithm to *break* the line before the word "headings" instead of resorting to an overfull box. None of the options in `align` seem to have any effect here.

All help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Add `broad` to the list of `align` values, e.g. `align={flushleft,broad,nothyphenated}`.

Comment: I don't think that is possible in general. You can cover 99.9% of the ground with Wolfgang's answer, but if you have a gigantic unbreakable word that is wider than the entire text block, an overfull box is unavoidable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid overfull lines with ragged text which can appear when you disable hyphenation you can add the `broad` keyword to the `align` option to improve line breaking.

```
\definefont [SectionFont] [Italic sa 4]

\setuphead
  [section]
  [ style=SectionFont,
    align={flushleft,broad,nothyphenated},
   number=no]

\starttext

\section{Test overfull headings}

\samplefile{knuth}

\stoptext
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. That, indeed, solved my problem. I will have to investigate, if it works consistently to cover most of the situations that I'm facing, but right now this seems to be the easiest and most practocal solution.

Answer (score 3):

> However, I am now facing the situation that I would really like to absolutely, totally, ultimately and always prevent overfull lines in a section head. I.e. no matter how "bad" the line becomes according to TeX's algorithm, it should never resort to overfull lines.

<s>You've pretty much exhausted the options available in ConTeXt for this problem.</s> See Wolfgang's comment below for a much better way of solving this. Original answer below:

Luckily, there are still some Plain TeX options that we can use. I can think of 4 options here:

#### `\tolerance=10000`

This is suggested in the TeXbook:

> Alas, overfull boxes return; so try typing
>
> ```tex
> \tolerance=10000
> \input story
> ```
>
> in order to see what happens. TeX treats 10000
> as if it were "infinite" tolerance, allowing arbitrarily wide space;
> thus, a tolerance of 10000 will *never* produce an overfull box,
> unless something strange occurs like an unhyphenatable word that is
> wider than the column itself.

#### `\emergencystretch=\maxdimen`

Again from the TeXbook:

> If you want to avoid overfull boxes at all costs without
> trying to fix them manually, you might be tempted to set
> `\tolerance=10000`; this allows arbitrarily bad lines to be acceptable
> in tough situations. But infinite tolerance is a bad idea, because
> TeX doesn't distinguish between terribly bad and preposterously
> horrible lines. Indeed, a tolerance of 10000 encourages TeX to
> concentrate all the badness in one place, making one truly unsightly
> line instead of two moderately bad ones, because a single
> "write-off" produces fewest total demerits according to the rules.
> There's a much better way to get the desired effect: TeX has a
> parameter called `\emergencystretch` that is added to the assumed
> stretchability of every line when badness and demerits are computed,
> in cases where overfull boxes are otherwise unavoidable. If
> `\emergencystretch` is positive, TeX will make a third pass over a
> paragraph before choosing the line breaks, when the first passes did
> not find a way to satisfy the `\pretolerance` and `\tolerance`.
> The effect of `\emergencystretch` is to scale down the badnesses so
> that large infinities are distinguishable from smaller ones. By
> setting `\emergencystretch` high enough (based on `\hsize`) you can be
> sure that the `\tolerance` is never exceeded; hence overfull boxes
> will never occur unless the line-breaking task is truly impossible.

#### `\rightskip=0pt plus 1fil`

From the TeXbook once more:

> For example, a person can set `\rightskip=0pt plus1fil`, and every
> line will be filled with space at the right. But this isn't a
> particularly good way to make ragged-right margins, because the
> infinite stretchability will assign zero badness to lines that are
> very short.

Here we are okay with lines that are very short, so we can happily do what it tells us not to do.

#### `\spaceskip=\fontdimen2\font plus \maxdimen minus \fontdimen4\font`

This has the effect of allowing the word spaces to stretch infinitely far, and produces a very different effect than the other options.

---

With this example, the first three options all produce the same effect:

(image won't upload, will edit in later)

while the last option has quite a different effect:

(image won't upload, will edit in later)

You can place any of these commands anywhere in the document, but for this purpose, it's easiest if you add them to the `style` key like so:

```tex
\setuphead[section][
  style=\tfe\em\emergencystretch=\maxdimen,
  align={flushleft, nothyphenated, fullhz, hanging, verytolerant, stretch},
  number=no,
  alternative=margin,
  after={\blank[4*line]},
]
```

In general, I'd prefer using `\emergencystretch=\maxdimen` over all the other options since it only takes effect if there are any overfull boxes.

Comment: There is a solution for the problem with the `broad` keyword which can be used with ragged text, e.g. `align={flushleft,broad,nothyphenated}`. Even `stretch` has a second mode with the `extremestretch` option (it sets the value to `10\bodyfontsize`).

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster That's a *much* better solution than I have. You should probably add that as an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate reply. This list was very helpful indeed. I'll be using Wolfgang's solution for the time being, but will also experiment with your ideas. The `\emergencystretch` technique, in particular, seems like a viable solution. Much appreciated!